# Identify main element in directive template

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive with the following template:

```
<div></div>
```

Now, whenever a method `m1` in the directive is run, I need to clear the `div` and  append other divs:

```
var div1 = element.first();
div1.empty();
var div2 = angular.element('<div/>');
div1.append(div2);
```

I cannot use an id in the root `div` as the directive may be used several times in the controller.

Problem is that element.first() doesn't work to identify the root `div`. Any ideas?

Comment: I think `element.after('<div/>')` should work, If you have jQuery included

Comment: this didn't work, sorry (I have jQuery included)

Answer (score 1):

Set a class on the div and do:

```
element[0].querySelector('your-class');
```

And it will give you the root div. This uses normal javascript but you can just take the same approach with jQuery.

Comment: How does this work with multiple instances of the same directive?  Wouldn't the class selector get all such divs and the directives would interfere with each other?

Comment: @ryanyuyu Not sure I understand but I do not think they would. He only needs to root div for each instance of the directive, which this provides. If I misunderstood the question he could do provide some more information.

Comment: I need to run `div1.empty();` but div1 is undefined (see my code in the question). div1 should be a jquery element